# Python server receives POST request data from iOS after it has timed out

Tags: ios, objective-c, python-2.7, post

I have an iOS application that can make POST requests and upload files like this. On the the other side I have a Python server waiting.

The problem I'm facing is that when iOS application gets to the part where it's suppose to send the request, it stalls. From what I can tell, some part of the request sending method works, because the server receives the POST call, but then it stalls there. It won't proceed until the request has either timed out or I stop the execution of the application. After that the server proceeds as normal and the weird thing is that it has somehow gotten all the data and can proceed as designed. It's the same with both synchronous and asynchronous, both in simulator and real device.

Here's the part of Objective-C that deals with the request

```
// Get the image before we start building the request
    UIImage *image = [[PageViewControllerData sharedInstance] photoAtIndex:self.startingIndex];
    NSData *temp = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);

    // The request with URL
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"address-to-the-server"]];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    // Boundary generation
    NSString *boundary = @"----block-end";

    // Data size
    //NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [temp length]];
    //NSLog(@"%@", postLength);

    // Content type
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    //[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; // not necessary as it's done automatically
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // Request's body building
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"temp_target.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:temp]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Attach the body to the request
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSLog(@"Sending data.");

    // Create request parameters
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;

    // and fire the request
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Here's part of the python server code:

```
def do_POST(self):

    print("POST method called")

    form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=self.rfile, headers=self.headers,environ=
    {'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST','CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],})

    print("Form read")
    ....
```

The device I'm using is iPhone 4 (7.1.2). On simulator I have tried iPhone 4s and iPhone 6. Server is sitting in Ubuntu environment in VirtualBox.

On server side, the first print message is shown, the second one is not. The second one appears after the request has either timed out or I stop the program execution.

If any of you were thinking about Content-Length problem then it probably is not that, because it gets applied automatically if I don't. And yes, I tried applying it myself, it changed nothing.

Server has been tested countless times with a regular browser, since it's capable of handing out a special form where one can upload pictures and it is working perfectly.

Any ideas what might be keeping the request on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so finally got it fixed.

Apparently the very last boundary line must have an additional "--" after the boundary string to signal the server that all the data has been sent and there is nothing more coming.

Basically this:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"temp_target.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:temp]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

has to be like this

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"temp_target.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:temp]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

(notice the very last line has two extra "--" right after the boundary string.

I was following multiple examples when doing this and none of them had that. Here's an [example guide](http://nthn.me/posts/2012/objc-multipart-forms.html). There are many examples here on stackoverflow.com as well and at least the ones I happened to see were all missing this. I guess something has changed over time (seeing the date of that guide), making this now a required part.

Thanks to my course mate that guessed the issue.